# what date format is this and how do I convert it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs plugin that returns time stamps that looks like this (when printed in the javascript console.)

`Sun Mar 30 2014 14:00:56 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

but when I store it in a MySQL database, it turns into this format

`2014-03-30T04:59:38.734Z` (this is a string)

my problem arises when I try to compare the two, it doesn't work because you can't compare two differently formatted dates. How do I make it that they are consistent? Preferably, how do I convert the second format into the first format?

Answer (score 0):

The first has been converted to a Local Date string, the second is in ISO format. To convert the ISO use toLocaleString()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Be aware toLocaleString() works off of the clients browser / computer settings and depending on what you're doing globalization could be a problem. I usually compare dates in ISO form, then switch them to a "prettier" format if needed for display to users.

Comment: More so I should say different browsers may handle toLocaleString() differently.